# Graphics Icons in google play store in my mobile

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, app-icons

When I open the *Google Play store* app, icons are missing in the app listings:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

This happens only to the *Google Play* app, where it happened from the very beginning, right when I'd bought the device (i.e. it didn't start only recently). I don't encounter it in other apps. Also, when visiting the Playstore with the device's web browser, there is no such issue: here all images are displayed fine, so it shouldn't be a network/firewall issue.

The device in question is a *Note Edge* running Kitkat (4.4.4).

Any idea what could cause this, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: No. I see all image in Playstore web browser

Comment: Did you empty the cache on the play store and play services apps?